# Setting a query string from Java's Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI uri);

Tags: java, html, url, uri, query-string

I have tried googling but I cannot find an answer. I am writing a pure Java Desktop application. The help system launches by using the Desktop class browse function and giving it a URI. When I add a "? then the URI fails in Java. I want to pass the program version number to my offline help page in the browser, but I cannot figure out how to set a query string.

I am running on RedHat 6. I am using this code:

```
uri = new URI("file", "", programPath, "version=1.0.3", "");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

I get an IOException on the browse function. All it says is that "Failed to show URI:"

If I take that full uri path and paste it in my browser, it works. I am completely stumped by this...

Comment: Fails how?  Can you give an example of the URI string?

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Download and run the demo code from [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) and paste your URI into the demo for a test. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you are testing your code and how you build the URI if you still need more help.

Comment: Did you look at the code from the tutorial? The code just accepts a string for the URI. Did you try that for your program? Did you print out the toString() representation to compare a hardcoded string with a generated String? Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem using a URI that we can access on the web. The code you provided doesn't tell us anything. We have no idea what programPath is.

Comment: It is a local path on my computer, the program is an offline desktop application.

Comment: I don't think a file URI supports a query string. I thought that was only for an HTTP URI. The query string is handled by the HTTP server, so unless you are running a server on your computer I don't think is will work. If you want to pass the version number then you need to build that into your file name, maybe by having a directory structure for each version. Again post your SSCCE that shows how the code works for a hardcoded URI.

Comment: Could you put the version variable in a hashbang fragment instead of the query? Since you have to handle it with JavaScript anyway, it is just as useful.

Comment: I am not even sure what a hashbag fragment is. I am guessing that you are referring to the fragment parameter in the URI class. It appears after the pound sign... I will have to try that when I have a chance at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I never got it working the way I wanted to, but if I use the URI constructor that just takes a string and then I feed it the path as normal which always worked and then add "# + versionNumberVar"; then it works! It is frustrating because it won't work with "?version=" + versionNumberVar but I have what I need finally. Also, those other constructors do not work for me which is surprising. Unfortunately the URI error messages are cryptic and it just says "Failed to show URI".

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from the way windows handle (or removes) query params for local html files. It may be related to security issues... Nevertheless I had the exact same requirements as you and finally found this answer by @arcticLord: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387920/259988

You have to introduce a temporary