# java open web page with querystring

Tags: java, uri, desktop

I need to open web page after clicking button in my java window app. My problem is that when I use

`URI testPage = new URI("file:///C:/index.html?param1&param2");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(testPage);`

opened page in my browser doesn't contain my querystring parameters, which are necessary to display page properly. How can I do that? Why is everything after "?" cut?

Comment: That's called a querystring.

Comment: Sure, my mistake, but how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a file URI supports a query string. The query string is handled by the HTTP server, so unless you are running a server on your computer I don't think it will work.

[Look for similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334436/setting-a-query-string-from-javas-desktop-getdesktop-browseuri-uri)

Comment: Yes, but JS code can still read the querystring; this should work.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me clearly. I just need to open my web browser with URI containing querystring, but instead of that I get browser window with URI without querystring. BTW when I just paste full URL with querystring my page looks fine.

Comment: I believe I got you. But when you are using a file protocol, the underlying java.net.URI will ignore the query string part. It is different than simply copy pasting the link in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in how java handles query strings, it is in how you local browser is handling file requests.  A quick test of an HTTP URL shows that this works just fine.  I tried this and it worked exactly as expected:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{
        URI test = new URI("http://google.com?test=monkey");
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: True, it works fine for online web page. The problem is that it doesn't work for local web page. This way is necessary for me, because my java app prepares presentation which is then displayed by js. My goal now is to give user way to test his presentation, before sending it to FTP server.

Comment: Yup. But that behavior is not controlled by java, and worse yet it will quite possibly vary between operating systems and even specific machines.  Normally what I do when I'm doing local testing, is spin up a Python SimpleHTTPServer, but I don't know how viable that is for your app.  Alternatively you could figure out how to spin up something similar in Java.

Comment: Ok, that is enoguh for me to know. I have an idea how to little rebuild my testing page and I hope that will work :)